# Dynatrace implementation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, dynatrace

How do I log a button tap event or a method call event in my Xamarin Forms (iOS) app for logging details in Dynatrace Dashboard.

Have followed the implementation process as mentioned in

https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/real-user-monitoring/setup-and-configuration/mobile-apps/development-frameworks/xamarin-nuget

But Unable to implement code to log events

Comment: "unable to implement" - what does this mean?  What have you tried?  Do you get an error, exception, or crash?  The docs you linked to show this sample `ReportEvent(eventName: string);`

Comment: var myAction = Agent.Instance.EnterAction("Tap on Confirm");
myAction.ReportEvent("Customer type");
myAction.LeaveAction();     How do I Access "Agent.Instance" in my View Model in Xamairn forms--- @Jason

Comment: step #5 of the docs tells you to create a `DependencyService`

Answer (score 0):

call using the below way using dependency service,

```
IDynatrace dynatrace = DependencyService.Get<IDynatrace>();
dynatrace.SendBizEvent("your business type event", new Dictionary<string, object> { });
```